Angular Client not able to include HTTPOnly cookie in requests to PHP server
Client Side is running on 4200 and Server side is on port 80
My index.php headers are
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

I've set an HTTPOnly cookie containing my  access token. For now, I've only implemented it to be generated when user logs in.
        $cookie_options = [
            'expires' => time() + 3600, // The cookie will expire in 10 minutes
            'path' => '/', // The cookie will be available on all paths
            'secure' => false, // The cookie will be sent over HTTP if the host is localhost, and HTTPS otherwise
            'httponly' => true, // The cookie will not be accessible via JavaScript
            'sameSite' => 'Lax'
        ];
        $cookieSet = setcookie('accessToken', $accessToken, $cookie_options);
        if ($cookieSet) {
            $cookieR =  'Cookie was set successfully, cookie name: ' . $cookieSet;
        } else {
            $cookieR = 'Failed to set cookie';
        }

        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Login Successful', 'token' => $token, 'role' => $role, 'cookie' => $cookieR));
        die();

The cookie shows up on network tab only when I login, in Set-Cookie.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2024 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.12
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: accessToken=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MTMwMjQ5OTIsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6MSwibmFtZSI6IkpvbmF0aGFuIE1jTWFtYSIsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9fQ.k4bYOZXLqKPhP-IQtqlBan3C4DAMY1ZMN7T-2b9YC1w; expires=Sat, 13 Apr 2024 16:16:32 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Content-Length: 357
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

CONFLICT  When I try to upload a file using this function:
uploadFiles(file: File, request: string): Observable<any> {
const uploadData = new FormData();
const url = `${API_URL}${request}`;

uploadData.append('userFile', file, file.name);

return this.http.post(url, uploadData, {
  observe: 'events',
  withCredentials: true
});

}
I get this response:
no cookie{"status":{"remarks":"success","message":"Successfully uploaded a file"},"payload":"{\"fileId\":22,\"fileSize\":6601,\"parentFolderID\":null,\"fileExt\":\"php\",\"fileDateCreated\":\"2024-04-13 23:20:43\",\"fileDateDeleted\":null,\"fileName\":\"index\"}","prepared_by":"GCLOUD TEAM","timestamp":{"date":"2024-04-13 23:20:43.343595","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Manila"}}

And that's "no cookie" because I want to check if client side really does include cookies generated by the server. However, I dont see any cookie being set on the Application tab as previously mentioned.
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'POST':
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        if($request[0] !== 'login') {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['accessToken'])) {
                echo 'your cookie has been received!';
            } else {
                echo 'no cookie';
            }
        }
        switch ($request[0]) {
            case 'login':
                echo json_encode($loginContr->loginUser($data));
                break;

            case 'fileupload':
                echo json_encode($fileUpload->fileUpload($_FILES['userFile'], $userID));
                break;

I'm wondering how I can use that http only cookie generated by server and include it in every request by client. And why no cookie is being set in Application Tab
Additional Info: I use chrome, and have enabled third party cookies.
Somewhat similar: Set cookies for cross origin requests

Why are you using cookies for authentication purposes? Why don't you send it inside the Authorization header?

@EyadBereh I use document.cookie to store the JWT token (generated from server-side) to client-side, so that I can add the JWT token to Authorization header when I make outward requests from client to server.  However, I read that this makes my website vulnerable XSS attacks, and using HttpOnly cookie is better because it has samesite, secure and strict flags

use localstorage
